# Opera calculating incorrect height on absolute positioned div with top margin

Tags: height, opera, margin, viewport, absolute

**Scenario:**
header height + content height extends beyond viewport which has overflowing content hidden. Content is absoultely positioned with top 0, bottom 0, and has a top margin equal to the header height so it doesn't overlap it.

**Opera defect:**
Opera seems to be calculating the height of the absolutely positioned div (with respect to the viewport) BEFORE it considers the top margin of the element. This is for content (plus header) that extends beyond the bottom edge of the viewport where overflowing content is hidden (`html{overflow:hidden}`).
Other browsers seem to calculate the height after applying the top margin which results in an overall shorter height for that absolutely positioned div. Not Opera though, the aboslutely poistioned div is the same size as the viewport and extends beyond the viewport the length of the header.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/66VLw/5/)

**Workaround:**
Do not use a top margin with absolutely positioned divs that extend beyond viewport where viewport overflow is hidden. Instead, set the `top` style on the absolutely postioned div to the length of what the top margin was.
`margin-top: 0px;`
`top: 68px;`
This will make Opera and all the other browsers behave consistently.